# SAS Function Search

Tags: function, sas

my data set includes billed amounts & refunds. I'd like to match billed amounts and refunds together when relevant. I have a unique identifier which allows me to see which rows should be added. I've done this before easily enough using R Software but my data set is on SAS.

Can anyone suggest a function in the Query Builder that will allow me to do this & perhaps illustrate how it is best used?

A snip of my data set is below.
[image]

Comment: Are you looking to get to 1 record per unique ID?  That seems to be where this is going.

Comment: Dompazz, yes I am.

Comment: OK, @Jetsler has the best answer code wise. It is what I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

Many different possible ways. e.g. `Proc SQL`, `Proc Means`, `Proc Summary`, `Data Step` using double DOW.
Very easy would be `group by` in `Proc SQL`

```
proc sql;
create table data_want as
  select a.*, sum(a.total) as new_total
    from data_have a
      group by a.UniqueID
    ;
quit;
```

Regarding the query builder (which will just produce `proc sql` code):

1. When selecting variables for the query there is a column `Summary` behind every selected variable. Set this to SUM for the `total` Variable.
2. You will be asked to choose a GROUP Variable. Select your unique ID here.

Comment: Jetzler thanks for your incredibly speedie response. My question omitted an important point.  Can this be done using the query builder.  I have now added this to my question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: As the query builder produces proc sql code you can just use the given example. I will adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sort input_data; by 'Unique Identifier' /*In_date*/;
run;

data result;
  set input_data;
  by 'Unique Identifier';
  retain res_total 0;
  if first.'Unique Identifier' then res_total = total;
  res_total + total;
  if last.'Unique Identifier' then output;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Still struggling with this:  I have the following code in the query builder. But the query builder doesn't like the 'group by' command, any suggestions?                                                                    CASE  
   WHEN (sum(t1.Total_USD) group by t1.Unique_identifer = 0)
   THEN 'Refund_match'
WHEN (sum(t1.Total_Loc_Cur) group by t1.Unique_identifer  = 0)
   THEN 'Refund_match'
   ELSE 'Not_Refund'
END

Comment: why you can't use user program code and write anything there insted of Query Builder?

Comment: managed to do it the a program & then joined back to the original data table. Thanks for your help